# October CMS specify attachment_type for system_files table

Tags: laravel-5, octobercms, octobercms-backend

for the attachment_type field in the system_files table, a string with the class name is automatically generated. How to set specify class string?

looks like this now:

```
public $attachOne = [
    'main_photo' => [
        'System\Models\File',
        'delete' => true,
    ]
];
```

Comment: can you be more detailed what you try to achieve so we can guide you with full picture

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here, but I guess you're not wanting to have the full class stored in in the `attachment_type` column of the `system_files` table.

What you can do is define a morph map in the `boot()` method of your plugin's `Plugin.php` file.

So if you had a plugin in the `October\Shop` namespace, with a `Product` model you could do this.

```
// Plugin.php

<?php

namespace October\Shop;

use System\Classes\PluginBase;
use October\Rain\Database\Relations\Relation;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Relation::morphMap([
            'product' => \October\Shop\Models\Product::class,
        ]);
    }

    /** The rest of your plugin.php file **/
}
```

You can read about this in the docs.

[OctoberCMS Version 2 docs: Custom Polymorphic Types](https://docs.octobercms.com/2.x/database/relations.html#custom-polymorphic-types)

[OctoberCMS Version 3 docs: Custom Polymorphic Types](https://docs.octobercms.com/3.x/extend/database/relations.html#custom-polymorphic-types)